# Delegation waring with the data source in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I have set the max limit to 2000 , when could see the same delegation warnings in my code using power apps with SQLdata source as connector

ClearCollect(sequencerUser,Filter('[dbo].[sequenceIDs]',User().Email in EmailAddress).sequenceID);
ClearCollect(onstartselectedreqeustfromleft,
SortByColumns(
Filter(
Filter('[dbo].[student]',IsApproved =1 ),
sequenceID in sequencerUser
)
,"RequestDate",SortOrder.Descending)
);

I am facing the blue line highlighted with delegation warning for **User().Email in** and **sequenceID in** as it wont support with larger dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround trick:
Save your User().Email as variable
Set(gblUserEmail, User().Email)
Use the variable in your query...
Change user().Email to gblUserEmail

Let me know if you get it fixed